# Bootstrap Modal Popup display as double layer in ASP.NET and shifts content when popups

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, master-pages, bootstrap-modal

I never had an experience with Bootstrap modal popup before. But in a recent theme purchase that was fully bootstrap based they demoed modal popups too which was perfectly working on their HTML page. But when I integrate in my master page, everything working fine. But the modal popup alone shows as double as you can see in the image below
[image]

I didnt get any idea why it behaves likes this when everything in the HTML page and ASPX page are alike. Also when the modal popup shows, there is a shifting like thing goingon on the page or a kinda small jumping towards the right when the modal popup comes.

**Here is my modal popup code**

```
 <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="mytestmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And here is the button code**

```
 <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mytestmodal">
    <i class="fa fa-copy"></i>| Clone Data
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that jumping, edit it's CSS

```
body.modal-open{
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks friend, that fixed my shifting problem. But do you have any idea why that double boxed modal?

Answer (score 0):

The lateral shifting is [a known open bug in Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855).
Assuming your modal isn't long enough to need to be scrolled, you could try [this supposed workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960162/bootstrap-3-modal-fires-and-causes-page-to-shift-to-the-left-momentarily-brows):

```
.modal {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-open {
  overflow: auto;
}
```