# Ensure that the page stays unscrollable when the modal is open, while still keeping the scrollbar visible

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make it so that when a modal is opened, the user won't be able to scroll the page. However, if I simply add `overflow: hidden` to the `<body>`, the scrollbar will disappear quickly and the content suddenly shifts to the right, which looks pretty ugly. How can I 'freeze' the scroll in the position **I'm currently at**, keep the scrollbar visible and make sure that all the features like, for example, `hide on scroll` on the `<header>`, under the modal with its dark underlay won't be triggered?

I tried different approaches, one of which adding this directly to the `<body>`:

```
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

In this case the scrollbar is visible, we can't scroll, but `position: fixed;` makes the viewport jump to top when you open a modal, so this approach isn't ideal (I don't need any jumps).

I use Vue and here's how my App.vue template looks like:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <AppModal></AppModal>
        <AppHeader></AppHeader>
        <AppMain></AppMain>
        <AppFooter></AppFooter>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm looking for the most laconic solution **without involving JS**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to reproduce the issue of the content shifting we need to have a fixed header. (this part was missing from your question). Now if the body goes `overflow-y:hidden`, the scrollbar would disappear thus causing the content shift in the header.

The fix, is having the header inside a container with a counteracting `overflow-y:scroll` that will appear as soon as the body loses its scrollbar.

```js
btn.onclick = btn3.onclick = function(ev) {
  document.body.classList.add("fixed")
}

btn2.onclick = function(ev) {
  document.body.classList.remove("fixed")
}


// hide on scroll
let lastScrollY = window.scrollY;
var header_container = document.querySelector(".header-container");
const handleScroll = () => {
  if (lastScrollY < window.scrollY && window.scrollY >= 50) {
    header_container.classList.add("hidden")
  } else {
    header_container.classList.remove("hidden")
  }
  lastScrollY = window.scrollY;
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0;
}

body.fixed {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.header-container {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  
  /* meh - not supported in opera? */
  scrollbar-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.75) rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.75);
}

.header-container.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

body.fixed .header-container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body .modal {
  display: none;
}

body.fixed .modal {
  display: block;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0;
  top: 0;
  background: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px purple;
}

.modal {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
      header, <button id="btn3">open modal</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <h1>hello world, please scroll and/or open modal</h1>
  <p>sdflkjsdfl kjsf</p>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <p>sdflkjsdfl kjsf</p>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <p>sdflkjsdfl kjsf</p>

  <button id="btn">open modal</button>


  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <p>sdflkjsdfl kjsf</p>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <p>sdflkjsdfl kjsf</p>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <p>sdflkjsdfl kjsf</p>

  <div class="modal">
    <h2>hello i am modal</h2>
    <button id="btn2">close</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works, although your example doesn't show how it works with `hide on scroll` effect on header. In my case, it works, besides `hide on scroll` when I close the modal. I've made a repro, so you can see what I mean - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-h7zjgl?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FAppHeader.vue. I suppose because I have a `.general-wrapper` as the scrollable element, instead of body, now turning to `window` in `AppHeader.vue` doesn't make sense. I can create a `window.generalWrapper` global variable, but it seems like it makes it more complicated. Any solution?

Comment: For me it would be better if you made an HTML example here.  Maybe try to hide the `.header-container` on scroll, and not the `.header`? I have modified my example.

Comment: yeah I think that works. May I ask why the scrollbar shrinks vertically and becomes the size of the height of header when I click on the open modal button in your example?

Comment: because the vertical scroll bar is around the `header` and not the `body`.  that's the whole point of *this* non-perfect solution.  maybe if you colorize the small scrollbar it won't be much noticeable below the modal.  example edited.

Comment: so basically with this approach the scrollbar will disappear when we open the modal, but it's just won't make the content shift to right?

Comment: if it works here then hopefully yeah. actually, similar issue occurred in bootstrap 3 modal (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960162/bootstrap-3-modal-fires-and-causes-page-to-shift-to-the-left-momentarily-brows)